# C++ segmentation fault using erase in a vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault during my code and I was wondering why. I am taking a guess its something with the `vector.erase()` function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

long long gcd(long long x, long long y);
std::vector<long long> factor(long long x);
typedef std::vector<long long> vectorNum;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    long long unFriendly;
    long long friendly;
    long long counter = 0;
    std::cin >> unFriendly;
    std::cin >> friendly;
    vectorNum n;
    n = factor(friendly);

    for(long long x = 0;x < unFriendly;x++){
        long long num = 0;

        std::cin >> num;
        counter = gcd(friendly, num);
        for(long long y = n.size() - 1;y >= 0;y--){
            vectorNum temp(n);
            if(counter % n.at(y) == 0){
                n.erase(n.begin() + y);
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout<<n.size();
    n.clear();

}

long long gcd(long long x, long long y){
    while(y != 0){
        long long a = x % y;
        x = y;
        y = a;
    }
    return x;
}

std::vector<long long> factor(long long x){
    long long y;
    long long root = sqrt(x);
    std::vector<long long> vectorSet;
    for(y = 2; y <= root;y++){
        if(x % y == 0){
            vectorSet.push_back(y);
            vectorSet.push_back(x / y);

        }
    }
    vectorSet.push_back(x);
    return vectorSet;
}
```

Any kinds of insight would be perfect! Thanks in advance.
This is both the functions that are being called. Both of the `gcd()` and the `factors()` function as requested.

Comment: where's the implementation of gcd and factor

Comment: The for() loop with erase() in it looks a bit strange, why are you copying the whole vector to a stack one? Also after erasing y may go out of range, hence the crash you observe.

Comment: `y` goes out of range if `n` is empty. Are you running under a debugger? I ask because it took me less than a minute running under the Visual Studio debugger to see that this code throws `std::out_of_range`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(long long x = 0;x < unFriendly;x++){
    long long num = 0;

    std::cin >> num;
    counter = gcd(friendly, num);
    for(long long y = n.size() - 1;y >= 0;y--) {  // <-- n.size() == 0, 0U - 1 is huge
        vectorNum temp(n);
        if(counter % n.at(y) == 0){  // <-- y is huge, throws std::out_of_range
            n.erase(n.begin() + y);
        }
    }
}
```

I would strongly recommend running your code under a debugger. The Visual Studio debugger when running your code pretty quickly displayed this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your program will crash if `friendly` is 0. This is because the `factor` function will push 0 to the return vector. Inside your inner most loop, accessing `n.at(y)` will give the value 0 and dividing `counter` by 0 generates an exception that segfaults your application.